# Epsilon delta proof of a limit problems

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing

I am attempting to decipher the word of Stewart but I can't really understand any of the epsilon delta stuff. I watched several videos online and I have a better understanding but I still don't quite get how to do the math as no one really describes that part. As far as I understand I need to find the distance between x and delta that is less than delta and greater than zero that will coorespond to an epsilon (y).

So I have the problem
$$
\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{2+4x}{3}=2
$$
so I do some algebra magic and I get $x=1$ but from there I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Could you describe the magic? The limit is at $x = 1$, so that seems okay.

Comment: Oh I just meant I multiplied by 3, subtracted 2 and then divided by 4.

Comment: I'll try to write something later, but [here's a search for related questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=epsilon-delta). There are worked problems in a lot of these threads and that might help you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The construction of an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof is usually exactly opposite its presentation.  This should be a good example.  Given $\epsilon$, you need to be able to produce some $\delta$ such that for all $x$ with $|x-1|<\delta$, $\frac{2 + 4x}{3} - 2|<\epsilon$.

How do you do this?  You (usually) need some formula to produce $\delta$ *in terms of* $\epsilon$.  So start with the expression you need, 
$$\bigg|\frac{2 + 4x}{3} - 2\bigg|<\epsilon,$$
and start solving for $x$ in terms of $\epsilon$.

I'll let you work out the details here; it's a simple algebraic exercise.  At the end, you'll get something like 
$$\bigg|x - 1\bigg| < \frac{3}{4}\epsilon.$$

Ah-hah! Now you have produced a constraint on $|x-1|$ in terms of $\epsilon$.  If I give you $\epsilon$, you can pick $\delta < \frac{3}{4}\epsilon$ and, as you can quickly verify, this $\delta$ will satisfy the $\epsilon$ bound. In fact, it has to --- that's how you made it.

The take-home lesson here, again, is that the way you *build* the proof is backwards. Start with what you want and backsolve for what you need.  Then when you write the proof out, you know how to choose $\delta$, so you can quickly verify that $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{2 + 4x}{3} = 2.$

Comment: So if I am given a number I just multiply it by 3/4 and that is my x value?

Comment: Right. Remember, the limit of a function at a point, if it exists, is the value the function approaches as its input approaches the point.  So the limit exists at $p$ and is $L$ ($\lim_{x\to p}f(x) = L$) if you can make the function gets as close as you please ($|f(x) - L|<\epsilon$) by making $x$ very close to $p$ ($|x-p|<\delta$).  Think of it as a game: I set how close you have to get (within $\epsilon$), and you have to be able to pick $\delta$ so that everything less than $\delta$ from $p$ gets sent closer than $\epsilon$ to $L$.

Comment: I don't get it, can't I just make up numbers? They have to work. Why don't I just make up a number .5 and plug that in to find the difference?

Comment: Because you have to be able to find a $\delta$ for EVERY $\epsilon$ that I give you.  $0.5$ might work if I give you $2$, but if I give you $0.000001$, then $0.5$ won't work any more.

Comment: I don't understand this at all and Steward has 8 definitions and several proofs of epsilon delta and they all seem to either say nothing or they disagree with eachother. If you give me .000001 then can't I just add or subtract that from the limit and then plug that in for x?

Comment: Hmm.  Are you trying to solve for $x$?

Comment: I am not sure, I am just trying to do the homework. "Prove the statement using the epsilon delta definition of a limit."

Comment: @Jordan - the definition of a limit, paraphrased a bit, is "No matter how small you make $\epsilon$, I'll be able to choose a small enough $\delta$ to make the inequality work out". The key point is that I don't have to choose $\delta$ first; I can wait till you've chosen $\epsilon$, then calculate a $\delta$ that depends on your $\epsilon$.  So I can't just pick $\delta = 0.0001$ and hope for the best, because you could choose an $\epsilon$ that's really small, and that makes the inequality false. I need to find a way of expressing $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$, to make the inequality work.

Comment: Might I add, Jordan, that the definition of the limit *is a logical implication*. Think of it as P -> Q (P implies Q). In this case, the statement P is that "x is close enough to delta" and the Q is "f(x) is close enough to epsilon"... more or less. 
You might not know that to prove P -> Q, you **assume P** and **deduce Q**

Comment: So that means that you can chose the value of the function as close to the limit as you want and that there should be an x value with a difference to the limit that is positive but smaller than the function change value?

Comment: @Jordan - Kind of, but by choosing $\epsilon$, you're actually choosing a whole range of values close to the limit (basically from $f(x) - \epsilon$ to $f(x) + \epsilon$; and saying that a whole range of $x$ values will map into this range.

Comment: Is epsilon larger or smaller than delta?

Comment: @Jordan - could be either, it depends on the question.  In this particular case, $\delta$ has to be smaller.

Answer (score 4):

In order to calculate the limit using $\epsilon-\delta$ we have to prove that:

$ \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{2+4x}{3}=2 \Longleftrightarrow ( \forall \epsilon >0) (\exists \delta >0) ( \forall x) |x-1|< \delta \Longrightarrow |\frac{2+4x}{3}-2|<\epsilon$

So, choosing $ \delta= \frac{3}{4}\epsilon$ we get:

$ |\frac{2+4x}{3}-2|=\frac{4|x-1|}{3} <\frac{4 \delta}{3} =\epsilon$.

Comment: What is the upside down A, what is the backwards E and why do you have arrows points both ways and some only one way? Why are you multiplying upsidedown A with things that are larger than 0?

Comment: These are shorthand for logical statements. $\forall$ = "for every," $\exists$ = "there exists some ... such that," $\Rightarrow$ = "implies," $\Leftrightarrow$ = "if and only if."  So, for example, $\forall\epsilon > 0 \exists\delta > 0 \forall x |x-1|<\delta \Rightarrow |\frac{2+4x}{3}-2|<\epsilon$ translates to "for each $\epsilon > 0$ there is some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$, if $x$ is less than $\delta$ away from $1$, $\frac{2 + 4x}{3}-2$ is less than $\epsilon$ away from $2$.

Comment: @Jordan: $\forall= \text{for all}, \quad \exists=\text{exist}$

Comment: The equivalence you wrote after *we have to prove that* is a tautology, hence it cannot be what one has to prove.

Comment: The sentence with "we have to prove that" ends just before the double arrow.

Comment: @David: I hope you do not recommend such a writing, especially in the answer to a question of this level.

Comment: No, I absolutely don't.  At the very least, I would have written some words on a separate line, in place of the double arrow.  Also, since it's supposed to be an explanation, not a proof, I would have put some words explaining how to get to $\delta = \frac{3}{4}\epsilon$.

Comment: @David: Then we agree.